# Error-checking for outbounded char-Array - using std::cin

Tags: c++, error-handling, cin

How can I make an error checking of outbounding the charlength when using std::cin?

```
char _charArr[21];
bool inputNotVerified = true;
while (inputNotVerified) {
     cout << "input a string no more than 20 chars: ";
     cin >> _charArr;  
 // if the errorchecking works the boolean should be set to false 
}
```

As stated in the comment above - the only thing that can break the loop is when the input is correct - that is no more than 20 characters. But how do i implement it?

I have tried to make a condition out of strlen(_charArr) but without success.

Comment: What happens *if* the user enter a string longer than 20 characters? Then you have buffer overflow. Use `std::string` and check its length.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - I have to use char* according to the assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`std::istream::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline):

```
if (std::cin.getline(_charArr, sizeof _charArr) && std::cin.gcount()) {
    // ...
}
```

`std::istream::getline()` will only read a maximum of `count` characters which is provided by the second argument. `gcount()` is for checking if at least one character has been read.

Comment: nice, but I had to add cin.ignore() and cin.clear();